# Merging objects into array with existing keys

Tags: javascript

I am creating the following object multiple times:

```
id : {
    "hp" : hp,
    "row" : startY,
    "square" : startX
}
```

and I want to make an array of those object using `id` as the key, to have an object that will look like this:

```
1 : {
    "hp" : 1,
    "row" : 2,
    "square" : 3
},
2 : {
    "hp" : 4,
    "row" : 5,
    "square" : 6
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: where do you get your IDs for each object?

Comment: the second one is hash, not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that will give you the array of objects like you want:

**[SEE WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RMBJN/4/)**

Code below:

```
var model = { id : {
    "hp" : "",
    "row" : "",
    "square" : ""
} }

function keystempl(args)
{
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args,0);
    var templ = args[0];
    var newo ={};

    var keys = [];
    for(var k in templ) 
    {
        keys.push(k);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
    {
        newo[keys[i]] = args[i + 1]; 
    }
    return newo; 

}

var arr = [];
var obj = keystempl([model["id"],"myhp","myrow","mysquare"]);
var obj2 = keystempl([model["id"],"myhp2","myrow2","mysquare2"]);

arr.push(obj);
arr.push(obj2);
```

An example usage would be like this:

```
var myarray = [];

myarray.push(keystempl([model["id"],"myhp","myrow","mysquare"]));
myarray.push(keystempl([model["id"],"myhp2","myrow2","mysquare2"]));
//YOUR ARRAY "myarray" NOW HAS TWO OBJECTS IN IT WITH THOSE VALUES
```